# Angular js script is not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started angular js and goiong through a tutorial and have this code which doesn't work.

Please enlighten the mistake

code is:

```
       <html data-ng-app="">
       <head>
          <title>My script 2 ANJS</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
           <h3>Adding a simple controller</h3>
           Name : <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> {{name}}
           <br/>

           <ul>
           <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
           </ul>
           </div>

           <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

           <script>
           function SimpleController($scope) {
                 $scope.customers=[
                                  { name:'Mayank', city:'bhopal'},
                                  { name:'Ankit', city:'bhopal'},
                                  { name:'kapil', city:'sagar'},
                                  { name:'moongoo', city:'pune'}
                                  ];
                                  }
           </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: NO just the script is not working in browser

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bhaTnYWVvWQbxGCKG4ER?p=preview I created a working plunkr for you

Comment: You have not defined your angular app. When you define your app pass $scope as the dependency so that view gets binded with the controller.

Comment: Corrected your mistakes:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RBN6Dj1vxkEFAUdGpoq1?p=preview